# not recoginzed Resource only in out folder and gradle run

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx

I am having a problem running my simple javafx application with gradle.

I have the blank standard sample.fxml file:

```
<GridPane fx:controller="de.hhn.se.pmt.flowertours.controllers.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

And in my src folder Intellij and gradle do not complain. gradle build executes successfully but gradle run always fails on the `xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"` line.

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'com.github.spotbugs' version '1.6.5'
}

apply plugin: 'application'
group 'de.hhn.se.pmt'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

mainClassName  = 'de.hhn.se.pmt.flowertours.Main'

allprojects{
    compileJava {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
        sourceCompatibility '1.8'
        targetCompatibility '1.8'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs "libs"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project (':gen')

    compile name: 'orm'
    compile name: 'jfxrt'

    compile group: 'com.jfoenix', name: 'jfoenix', version: '1.2.0'
    //logging with slf4j
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.24'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.25'
    //use JUnit 5
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1'

}
```

The added library omr and the subproject gen are not used yet and shouldn't be executed (so they shouldn't be the problem). The `jfxrt` Library was a try to fix it and is not neccessary.

My Main.java looks like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * "main" method that starts the program.
     *
     * @param args start parameter
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It looks like on runtime there are javafx libraries missing, but including the `jfxrt` with `runtime name: 'jfxrt'` does not solve the problem.

What did I do wrong? Is it a problem I have to fix in Intellij?

Comment: `Is it a problem I have to fix in Intellij?` If this fails from command line using Gradle then problem in build.gradle configuration. Please post the actual error you get and JDK you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make it clear, I haven't found any real good answer - javafx and gradle are just not friends and the implemented version of intellij does not make it easier.

The created Jar-File from the gradle plugion `application` does not include needed javafx files - you need to include new dependencies from [openjfx](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle) to actually build a running javafx jar file.

This is the setup for the dependencies and is not really needed:

```
def currentOS = org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current()
def platform
if (currentOS.isWindows()) {
    platform = 'win'
} else if (currentOS.isLinux()) {
    platform = 'linux'
} else if (currentOS.isMacOsX()) {
    platform = 'mac'
}
```

This has been added to my dependencies:

```
compile "org.openjfx:javafx-base:11:${platform}"
compile "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:11:${platform}"
compile "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11:${platform}"
compile "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:11:${platform}"
```

These additional settings include every src file in your jar-file - but this is a work in progress and maybe does not fit to your needs.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Implementation-Title": project.name,
                "Implementation-Version": version,
                "Main-Class": 'com.your.full.path.to.Main'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    from('src/main/resources/'){
        include('database.properties')
        into('')
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs "src/main/resources", "src/main/configs"
        }
    }
}
```